# SQLite: Edit Account

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to edit an user account based on the user id. I'm able to retrieve the user data from the database but there is a problem occurred when trying to update the data into the database after clicking the save button. I have no idea why the problem will occurred. May I know where did I make mistake?

**sql statement in app.py**

```
@app.route('/edit',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def edit():
    id = session['id']
    conn = get_db_connection()
    users = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ?',(id)).fetchall()

    form = EditForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        hashed_pw = generate_password_hash(form.password.data,"sha256")
        print(form.first_name.data, form.last_name.data, form.email.data, hashed_pw,  id)
        conn.execute('UPDATE User SET first_name = ?,last_name = ?,email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?',(form.first_name.data, form.last_name.data, form.email.data, hashed_pw,  id))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        message = "Data has been modify successfully"
        flash(message,'edited')
        return redirect(url_for('edit'))
    return render_template('edit.html',users = users, form = form)
```

**edit.html**

```
<form action="/edit" method="POST">
        <div>
            <h2 class="text-center fw-bold fs-2 mb-4 p-0 m-0">Edit Account</h2>
          {% for user in users %}
            <div class="input-group justify-content-between">
                
                <div class="form-floating mb-4" style="min-width: 230px;">
                    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John" value= "{{ user[1] }}"  />
                    {% if form.first_name.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors text-danger">
                        {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-4" style="min-width: 230px;">
                    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" value= "{{ user[2] }}"/>
                    {% if form.last_name.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors text-danger">
                        {% for error in form.last_name.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" value= "{{ user[3] }}" />
                {% if form.email.errors %}
                    <ul class="errors text-danger">
                    {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="Password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
                {% if form.password.errors %}
                    <ul class="errors text-danger">
                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <label for="passwordConfirmation">Confirm password</label>
                <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password again" />
                {% if form.password_confirmation.errors %}
                    <ul class="errors text-danger">
                    {% for error in form.password_confirmation.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            
            {% endfor %}
```

[[image: User data retrieved and displayed successfully in html page]

**This is the problem that occured when processing the update sql statement**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\desktop\phonebuddy\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\desktop\phonebuddy\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\desktop\phonebuddy\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\desktop\phonebuddy\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PhoneBuddy\app.py", line 127, in edit
    conn.execute('UPDATE User SET first_name = ?,last_name = ?,email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?',(form.first_name.data, form.last_name.data, form.email.data, hashed_pw,  id))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2022 16:29:50] "POST /edit HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**Output for the print() line**
[image]

Comment: Please examine the output of your function `generate_password_hash`. If you need more help please share your debugging results with us and add details on this function.

Comment: @Markus I have edited the post to display the debugging results. You may have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the type of parameter 4 is unsupported. The counting starts with 0, so we are talking about the `id`. Your debug output shows that `id` contains the [one-item python tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_tuple_one_item.asp) `(2,)`.

This is no problem for the select-statement where you only pass one parameter, because it can coup with both, single values and tuples. But if you pass more than just `id` like in your update statement, you get a tuple that contains a tuple.

Please check how you set `session['id']`. If you want to pass just one id then don't pass a tuple. If you want to pass a tuple then get the first value `id[0]` when you pass it to the update statement!